# com.htc.smartdim.sensor_eye has leaked IntentReceiver Error?

Tags: android, json, parsing, memory-leaks, compiler-errors

i tried to parse JSON but when i run the app, it closes unexpectedly and comes an error messages

> ```
> 08-01 18:41:42.724 387-397/? E/PNP_UPDATERD: inotify_add_watch failed. (No such file or directory)
> 08-01 18:31:42.724 387-397/? E/PNP_UPDATERD: inotify_add_watch failed. (No such file or directory)
> 08-01 18:30:12.344 988-988/? E/ActivityThread: Service com.htc.smartdim.sensor_eye has leaked IntentReceiver
> ```
>
> com.htc.smartdim.sensor_eye$CoverStateReceiver@271d6739 that was
>   originally registered here. Are you missing a call to
>   unregisterReceiver()?

android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.htc.smartdim.sensor_eye

> has leaked IntentReceiver
>
> com.htc.smartdim.sensor_eye$CoverStateReceiver@271d6739 that was
>   originally registered here. Are you missing a call to
>   unregisterReceiver()?
>
> ```
>                                                    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1003)
>
>                                                    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:767)
>
>                                                    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1775)
>
>                                                    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1755)
>
>                                                    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:495)
>
>                                                    at com.htc.smartdim.sensor_eye.register(sensor_eye.java:166)
>
>                                                    at com.htc.smartdim.sensor_eye.onStart(sensor_eye.java:285)
>
>                                                    at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:458)
>
>                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3072)
>
>                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:144)
>
>                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
>
>                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
>                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
>
>                                                    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:324)
>
>                                                    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:225)
>
>                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
>                                                    at
> ```
>
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>
> ```
>                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
>
>                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
>
> 08-01 18:30:12.354 386-691/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 2
>
>
> 08-01 18:30:12.354 386-691/? E/qdutils: int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to find HDMI node
> ```